# Remote Desktop Services - Licensing issue

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services

I am currently going through the process of setting up remote desktop services on one of our Windows 2012 hosts.

I have just activated the box as the remote desktop licensing server.

For the time being we are only going to be using the trial, I know there is a 90 or 120 day trial available.

My issue is with the remote desktop licensing server activated I am still only able to log in two concurrent users, is this a limitation to the trial or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You do something wrong. What does the event log say? In fact, even without licensing server you should be able to get more than 2 users in remote desktop mode. 2 connections smells way too much like your server still being in non-remote-desktop-services mode (i.e. running remote administration)

Comment: Yeah it's way too much of a coincidence. I'm going to go over the RD services config again and make sure everything is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this, for some unknown reason the Remote Desktop Manager service was failing to start, a reboot seemed to fix it and all is now well.